# Adding a button programmatically causes fatal error

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I'm creating an object detection app and I currently have it generating bounding boxes around the results. I'd like to create a button each time a new object is detected to be able to navigate to a description page for that object. I generate the observations in a file outside of my View Controller but I'm creating the button in the ViewController. I know the title is not **nil** but I get a fatal error when I add a subview.
Once an object is detected, I call:

```swift
 ViewController().showDetailView(buildingName: String(observationName))
```

And then in the View Controller it runs:

```swift
public func showDetailView(buildingName: String){ 
    let detailViewButton = UIButton() 

    detailViewButton.setTitle(buildingName, for: .normal) 

    detailViewButton.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:200,height: 100) 

    resultView.addSubview(detailViewButton) // error here

    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10.0, repeats: false) { timer in 
    detailViewButton.removeFromSuperview() 
    } 
}
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Finally, I receive this error once an object is detected:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

I've researched the problem and have found solutions (such as making sure the button is properly linked from the storyboard) but they don't seem to apply since I want to create the button programmatically.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "timer in" part is for

Comment: I wanted to show the button for 10 seconds before allowing new suggestions. I used a timer based on this article: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/117/the-ultimate-guide-to-timer

Comment: the timer is fine... I just don't know why you have the words "timer in"

Comment: @JoelFan that’s closure syntax. Strictly it could be `_ in` as the timer isn’t used but that’s just style.

Comment: does the exception happen right away, or only after 10 seconds?

Comment: It happens immediately when an object is detected (so when showDetailView() is run)

Comment: Does it still happen when you remove the timer code?  If that is the case, then you should remove that code from your question.

Comment: I would say that you are not setting enough fields in the detailViewButton.  Something is nil that is expected to be filled in.  Look for more sample code around creating a UIButton programatically.

Comment: I don't believe I need to add anything else - I've had buttons running with much less defined. Thanks for the response though

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `showDetailView(buildingName: String)` too early if `resultView` is declared as

`@IBOutlet var resultView: UIView!`

and when you call

```
ViewController().showDetailView(buildingName: String(observationName))
```

The view hierarchy hasn't been created yet.

But im not sure what you're trying to achieve as your statement is meaningless as `ViewController` is not presented anywhere.

Ensure that you call `showDetailView` after the `ViewController` instance has been added to a window.

Comment: The view is initialized and appears immediately. I have even waited a few seconds to detect something (to ensure it's not nil) and I still get the same error once an object is detected

Comment: What appears? Your code as posted creates a brand new instance of `ViewController` which isn’t presented in any window and then you then attempt to add a button to it. If `resultView` is nil your app will crash , that’s expected. You might have another instance of `ViewController` presented but that’s not the one you are calling `showDetailView` on.